# Sum of over primes $p$ of $x^{-p}$

Tags: prime-numbers, power-series, euler-mascheroni-constant, digamma-function

I was playing around with the following series
$$S(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{x^5}+\frac{1}{x^7}+\frac{1}{x^{11}}+...=\sum_{p\in primes}\frac{1}{x^p}$$
for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $|x|>1$.

And it seems, that for all $x\ge2$ the value of this sum is pretty close numerically to the following expression:
$$S(x) \approx \big(\sqrt{2}-1\big)\exp\big[-2(\psi(x) + \gamma-1)\big]$$
where $\psi(x)$ is digamma function and $\gamma$ is Euler–Mascheroni constant.

Is this just a coincidence or is there some explanation for this observation? And why does it work only for $x\ge 2$?

**EDIT:**

I'd like to show how I got my approximation. Because even though Nilotpal Sinha's answer shows that sharper estimate of $S(x)$ doesn't look like $e^{-2\psi(x)}$, I think there's something more than just coincidence of two terms in the Laurent series as $x\to\infty$ (maybe just another coincedence?..) because numerical agreement is much better.

So, if we calculate logarithm of the ratio of $\frac{S(n)}{S(n+1)}$ for $n\ge2$ we get the following:
$$\log\big(\frac{S(2)}{S(3)}\big)=0.99886...\approx1$$
$$ \log\big(\frac{S(3)}{S(4)}\big)=0.65714...\approx\frac{2}{3}$$
$$ \log\big(\frac{S(4)}{S(5)}\big)=0.493396...\approx\frac{1}{2}$$
$$ \log\big(\frac{S(4)}{S(5)}\big)=0.39565...\approx\frac{2}{5}$$
And so on...

And so, for example:
$$S(3) = S(2) \frac{S(3)}{S(2)} \approx S(2)e^{-1}$$
And:
$$S(5) = S(2) \frac{S(3)}{S(2)}\frac{S(4)}{S(3)}\frac{S(5)}{S(4)} \approx S(2)e^{-1-\frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{2}{5}}=S(2)e^{-2\big(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\big)}=S(2)e^{-2(H_4-1)}$$
where $H_n$ is n-th Harmonic number.

Noticing that $S(2)=0.41468...\approx\sqrt{2}-1$ and generalising $H_n$ to $\psi(x)$ we get
$$S(x) \approx \big(\sqrt{2}-1\big)\exp\big[-2(\psi(x) + \gamma-1)\big]$$

Comment: A kind of simpler conjecture : $\displaystyle S(x) \approx \exp(-2\psi(x))$ (with equivalence as $x\to \infty$)

Comment: @RaymondManzoni $\lim_{x\to\infty}\exp (-2 \psi (x))=0$

Comment: @Raymond Manzoni Yes, but I think it's a a bit rough approximation since $\psi(x)\sim\ln(x)$ and so $\exp(-2\psi(x))\approx\frac{1}{x^2}$ which is true as $x\to\infty$ but doesn't tell much about behavior of the series when higher order terms still matter.

Comment: @ssrg: I simply reformulated your approximation by searching the correct asymptotic constant replacing your $\big(\sqrt{2}-1\big)$ and obtained $\exp(2\gamma-2)$ => my reformulation. This should allow you to deduce (as you did) the limitations of your approximation (the primes after $2$ won't count much).

Comment: @Anixx Well $S(x) \sim \frac 1{x^2}$ as $x\to \infty$ so no conflict

Comment: @ssrg: from $6.3.18$ in [A&S](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm) you may deduce $\displaystyle\exp(-2\psi(x))\sim \frac{1}{x^2}+ \frac{1}{x^3}+ \frac{2}{3x^4}+O\left( \frac{1}{x^5}\right)$ : the two first terms are right...

Comment: To get better precision using the $\psi$ function you may use for example $$\displaystyle\exp(-2\psi(x)-\frac 2{3x^2}+\frac 4{3 x^3})\sim \frac{1}{x^2}+ \frac{1}{x^3}+ \frac{1}{x^5}+O\left( \frac{1}{x^6}\right)$$ I'll have to leave and wish you an excellent continuation,

Comment: @RaymondManzoni The first two terms are right, but the approximation numerically is much better even for small $x\ge2$ than you may expect from equality of first two terms in the expansions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your observation is a coincidence and is a consequence of the fact that the Laurent series expansion of $e^{-2\psi(x)}$ about the point $x=\infty$ is

$$
e^{-2\psi(x)} = \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x^3} + O\bigg(\frac{1}{x^{4}}\bigg) \tag 1
$$

and its first two terms have exponents $2$ and $3$ happen to be primes. If you replace $\psi(x)$ with any other function whose first tow terms are $2$ and $3$ you will get the same observation so there is nothing special that $\psi(x)$ is doing here.

A sharper estimate of $S(x)$ will help explain this coincidence further as shown below. Using the basic properties of primes we can get remarkably sharper estimates for $S(x)$. Every primes $\ge 5$ is of the form $6k \pm 1$. Sum up the geometric sequences $x^{-6k-1} + x^{-6k+1}$ for $k = 1,2,\ldots$ and add $x^{-2} + x^{-3}$, and taking advantage of the fact the the density of primes among the first few numbers of these form is high we get

$$
S(x) = \frac{x^7 + x^6 + x^4 + x^2 -x - 1}{x^3(x^6 - 1)} + O\bigg(\frac{1}{x^{25}}\bigg) \tag 2
$$

With this much sharper estimate you can see that $S(x)$ looks nothing like $e^{-2\psi(x)}$.

Comment: I accept your answer, but it is still a bit of a mystery to me, why my approximation is much better than just two first terms in the expansion of $e^{-2\psi(x)}$ and why $\frac{S(x)}{S(x+1)}\approx e^{\frac{2}{x}}$ (that's how I got my approximation).